# How do I make text in a column appear after the rows have been filled?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have made this spreadsheet to help our mechanical workshop track labour.  I have a problem on my spreadsheet where column K displays "follow up".  The end users (technicians and foreman) of this spreadsheet says it is difficult to read the spreadsheet as there's a column that displays FOLLOW UP on the 35" screen.  Column K is an IF statement that is dependent on TIME, DURATION and DUE OUT.

My question is: Is there a way to make column K blank until columns A to H are filled out?  Do I have to make a tickbox that makes conditionally formats K to be visible?

I found this article that may be applicable to my application.  Am I heading in the right direction?  [*UPDATE* Hide/unhide certain columns on some conditions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135902/update-hide-unhide-certain-columns-on-some-conditions)

Here is the link to my sheets:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VXabE1A7QGd-cN4e8Cb2ktsNz6VskN3RF3ApVRj5Hr8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your spreadsheet link is currently set so that only you can open the sheet with it, no one else. Please change the permission to "Anyone with the link."

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VXabE1A7QGd-cN4e8Cb2ktsNz6VskN3RF3ApVRj5Hr8/edit?usp=sharing

Changed, thanks for the feedback

Comment: See reply and solution below and in your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted 'RUNNING SHEET'!K2:K and placed the following formula in K2:

`=ArrayFormula({"";IF((TRIM(A3:A)="")+(TRIM(H3:H)=""),,"FOLLOW UP")})`

If either Col A or Col H (or both) are empty in any row, Col K will now be null. If *both* Col A *and* Col H are filled in, only then will Col K show "FOLLOW UP."

The opening `"";` is just a blank placeholder for K2 (sort of like a header of null), just so that the formula isn't in the active rows where data will be changing.

Comment: Thanks for the incite on how the formula would look.  I should be able to tailor that formula to my needs.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Please take a moment to mark my solution as "Best Answer." It effectively closes this post, and it will allow future site visitors to most easily find this answer if it matches their own search terms.